# How to highlight the current page number in pagination?

Tags: javascript, css

I have made a custom java script+css pagination for my page and I want to highlight the current page number , showonlyone() is a java script function that show the hidden text from a div number ID  that was hiden with css.I need o make the pagination highlight work ( to change the .but css background color to #720000 )

My code :

```
<div class="butpos">
Page:

<a id="bt1" href="javascript:showonlyone('post1');"  class="but"><span>1</span></a>                                         
<a id="bt2" href="javascript:showonlyone('post2');"  class="but"><span>2</span></a>                                          
<a id="bt3" href="javascript:showonlyone('post3');"  class="but"><span>3</span> </a>
<a id="bt4" href="javascript:showonlyone('post4');"  class="but"><span>4</span></a>
<a id="bt5" href="javascript:showonlyone('post5');"  class="but"><span>5</span></a>
</div>
```

I tried a pure css method with Id's :

```
.bt1 a#bt1,
.bt2 a#bt2,
.bt3 a#bt3,
.bt4 a#bt4,
.bt4 a#bt5
{
    background-color: #720000;
}
```

And a second method with css "curent" selector:

```
.but a.current{background-color:#720000;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load jQuery: add this before your < /body>

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="butpos">
    <a id="bt1" href="#" data-post-id="1" class="but"><span>1</span></a>                                         
    <a id="bt2" href="#" data-post-id="2" class="but"><span>2</span></a>                                         
    <a id="bt3" href="#" data-post-id="3" class="but"><span>3</span></a>                                         
    <a id="bt4" href="#" data-post-id="4" class="but"><span>4</span></a>                                         
    <a id="bt5" href="#" data-post-id="5" class="but"><span>5</span></a>                                         
</div>
```

JS

```
function showonlyone(postId) {
    // Your current showonlyone() code
    // (rename 'postId' to the param name of your function
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.but', '.butpos').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            $('.but.current', '.butpos').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');

            showonlyone($(this).data('postId'));

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.but {
    background-color: #0f0;
}

.current {
    background-color: #720000;
}
```

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/DNkap/

Comment: For both CSS blocks, you are using the same color... maybe that's the reason?

Comment: the color is diferent but I guess that I made some mistakes I haven't set the .current class. How to add a second class (.current) first is .but that design the button ? Should add only the .current but the problem is how to  design the buttons that are not in the current page I am new to css .Thanks

Comment: You can assign many classes to the same element, i.e. <a class="btn current" href="#">Link</a>... Are you using jQuery?

Comment: no , java script only for this pagination code . I tried what you show me but the color of of the buttons is the same to all buttons  this pagination script use java script to show hide some text div elements, the page do not have to reload . Should I use  jQuery code for this functionality?